# How can I define optional manual jobs in the first stage of my GitLab pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to have jobs in my first stage of our pipeline be manual and optional. I've defined the rules for this job as:

```
$-estimate | stable:
  stage: prepare
  extends: .plan_base
  variables:
    <<: *project-vars
    <<: *aws-stable-account-vars
    INFRACOST_VERSION: v0.9.13
    path: "terraform/live"
    post_condition: '{"has_diff": false}'
    percentage_threshold: "-1"
  script:
    - !reference [.infracost, before_script]
  rules:
    - <<: *rule-manual-run-branch
    - <<: *rule-never-run-draft
    - <<: *rule-never-run-tag
  allow_failure: true
```

The referenced rules come from here:

```
.rule-templates:
  [...]
  manual-run-branch: &rule-manual-run-branch
    if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
    when: manual
  [...]
  never-run-tag: &rule-never-run-tag
    if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    when: never
  never-run-draft: &rule-never-run-draft
    if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE =~ /Draft:/ || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE =~ /draft:/
    when: never
```

However, when I get to later stages in the pipeline,

```
deploy | stable:
  extends: .deploy_base
  stage: deploy-stable
  environment:
    name: stable
  variables:
    <<: *project-vars
    <<: *aws-stable-account-vars
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache zip
    - cd terraform/live
    - >
      terragrunt run-all apply \
        --terragrunt-non-interactive -auto-approve -lock-timeout=10m
  after_script:
    - . terraform/scripts/datadog-event.sh
  rules:
    - <<: *rule-manual-run-tag
  allow_failure: false
  needs:
    - tg-deploy | dev
    - tg-plan | stable
    - build+test | app
    - app-deploy | dev
```

I can not run `deploy | stable` until after the `estimate` job has completed.

None of my jobs have `needs: $-estimate | stable`.